# Getting a permission to see information for all the users in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I use the search box in Facebook and try to find a user, it shows me a list of all the matching users while I'm typing, along with additional information on them, such as the city they live in, and when I enter their wall/timeline, I can see more information. However, when I use Facebook Graph API to search for users, I get only basic information, and must have a permission for each user in the results to get more. Why is that? Is there a way to be able to see more information for all the users without having a permission for each of them?

Comment: no  the permission of item is must

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> […] and when I enter their wall/timeline, I can see more information.

Only if they have the visibility of their profile to public, though. Otherwise, you won’t see much on a user’s profile if you are not friends with them.

> However, when I use Facebook Graph API to search for users, I get only basic information, and must have a permission for each user in the results to get more.
>
> Why is that?

Because, naturally, you as a normal user browsing through a couple of search results on Facebook is something completely different than offering an app the capability to access all that information for every Facebook user from ID 1 to 99999999999, and then build some huge data mining thing upon it … I think that should be quite obvious.